# JQuery is not working Using Globe Internet Service Provider

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I am using JQuery for my web app and it is working fine. For some reason, it suddenly gets an error. But when I tried to change the Internet Service Provider, my web app works again. attached Image is the error from console.
[Error from console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PaUji.png)
Here is my code:

```
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();

            // Function to filter data while typing
            $('#searchInput').on('input', function() {
                var searchValue = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
                $('.employee-row').filter(function() {
                    $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchValue) > -1);
                });
                updateCounter();
            });
        });

        function filterEstablishments() {
            var statusFilter = document.getElementById("statusFilter").value;
            var fireDistrictFilter = document.getElementById("fireDistrictFilter").value;
            var cityFireStationFilter = document.getElementById("cityfirestationfilter").value;
            var startDateFilter = document.getElementById("startDateFilter").value;
            var endDateFilter = document.getElementById("endDateFilter").value;
            var tableRows = document.getElementById("establishmentTableBody").getElementsByTagName("tr");

            for (var i = 0; i < tableRows.length; i++) {
                var statusCell = tableRows[i].querySelector(".status");
                var fireDistrictCell = tableRows[i].querySelector(".fire_district");
                var cityFireStationCell = tableRows[i].querySelector(".city_fire_station");
                var dateOfIssuance1Cell = tableRows[i].querySelector(".dateofissuance1");
                var dateOfIssuance2Cell = tableRows[i].querySelector(".dateofissuance2");
                var status = statusCell.textContent;
                var fireDistrict = fireDistrictCell.textContent;
                var cityFireStation = cityFireStationCell.textContent;
                var dateOfIssuance1 = dateOfIssuance1Cell ? dateOfIssuance1Cell.textContent : null;
                var dateOfIssuance2 = dateOfIssuance2Cell ? dateOfIssuance2Cell.textContent : null;

                var statusMatch = statusFilter === "all" || (statusFilter === "Issued_FSIC" && status === "Issued_FSIC") || (statusFilter === "Issued_NTC" && status === "Issued_NTC");
                var fireDistrictMatch = fireDistrictFilter === "all" || fireDistrictFilter === fireDistrict;
                var cityFireStationMatch = cityFireStationFilter === "all" || cityFireStationFilter === cityFireStation;
                var dateMatch = true;

                if (startDateFilter && endDateFilter) {
                    var startDate = new Date(startDateFilter);
                    var endDate = new Date(endDateFilter);

                    if (status === "Issued_FSIC" && dateOfIssuance1) {
                        var issuanceDate = new Date(dateOfIssuance1);
                        dateMatch = issuanceDate >= startDate && issuanceDate <= endDate;
                    } else if (status === "Issued_NTC" && dateOfIssuance2) {
                        var issuanceDate = new Date(dateOfIssuance2);
                        dateMatch = issuanceDate >= startDate && issuanceDate <= endDate;
                    }
                }

                if (statusMatch && fireDistrictMatch && dateMatch && cityFireStationMatch) {
                    tableRows[i].style.display = "";
                } else {
                    tableRows[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }

            updateCounter();
        }

        function updateCounter() {
            var displayedRows = $('#establishmentTableBody').find('tr:visible').length;
            $('#recordCounter').text("Total: " + displayedRows);
        }
 $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#addModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
                var url = './create.php'; // Replace with the URL of your external page

                $.get(url, function(data) {
                    $('#addModalBody').html(data);
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

I tried to use different ISP and It works. But I need it to work in any ISP kindly help me

Comment: The error tells you that it could not load `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js`, what you could do is to download the version and include it locally in your solution, then ref to the local file

Comment: seems like you have an issue with code.jquery.com ... consider getting it from cdn.jsdelivr.net